# Cache closing tag error

Tags: templating, cache

I'm trying to using craft caching to cache a page without query string vars.

This tag

```
{% cache using key craft.request.path  %}

{% endcache %}
```

throws an error

Unexpected token "name" of value "using" ("end of statement block" expected)

This example is right from the Craft Docs, https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/cache

If I remove the "using ..." everything works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Works fine for me locally? Can you share the surrounding template code? Maybe some other template code is contributing to the error. Also, what's the URL look like when you get the error?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're running the latest version of Craft.  `using key` didn't come until Craft 2.2.